# Azure App Service Metrics - How to interpret Sum vs. Count related to requests?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

Below is a screen shot of an Excel file downloaded from Azure showing metrics on the number of requests our web app is getting.

[image]

Notice the rows highlighted in yellow and orange. The 128, 177 and 138 represents the sum of requests. The 8, 9 and 9 represent the count of requests. I don't know who to interpret these numbers. Does the 128 mean that from 12:55 to 13:00 there were 128 requests? And then from 13:00 to 13:05 there were 177 requests? If so, what does the count values of 8, 9 and 9 represent?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A metric is an aggregation over a time period.  Each metric value includes total/minimum/maximum/average/count properties.  In the above example, 177 means there were a total of 177 requests from 13:05 - 13:10.  The count property indicates the number of samples in that time period. If this is the Requests metric, you will likely be more interested in the Total property.

For more details, please refer to the following:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/monitor/metrics/list#metric

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/monitoring-supported-metrics#microsoftwebsites-excluding-functions

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/essentials/metrics-aggregation-explained#aggregation-types), the count means the number of records in the aggregated interval while the sum means the summation of values of those records.

So, for your example, it means that there were 8 records (measurements) & when you take a sum of all those 8 values you get 128.

Hope that clarifies.