# Azure App Service metrics aggregation for requests: why are Sum and Count different?

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-monitoring, azure-metrics-advisor

When looking at the metrics from our app services in Azure, I'm very confused at **Sum** and **Count**'s aggregation metrics for **requests**. They **should** be the **same**, according to the [MS tech doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/essentials/metrics-charts).

> Count: The number of measurements captured during the aggregation interval.
>
> ***When the metric is always captured with the value of 1, the count aggregation is equal to the sum aggregation.*** This scenario is common when the metric tracks the count of distinct events and each measurement represents one event. The code emits a metric record every time a new request arrives.

And this [MS tech doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/essentials/metrics-aggregation-explained) as well.

> Though not the case in this example, ***Count is equal to Sum in cases where a metric is always captured with the value of 1***. This is common when a metric tracks the occurrence of a transactional event--for example, the number of HTTP failures mentioned in a previous example in this article.

So, let say, for a specific period, if there are 10 HTTP requests, the count of requests is 10, then the sum of requests is also 10.

But ours are all different. Below are one web app service's Sum and Count metrices, you can see they are very different. But why?
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

From offical restapi, we can see that `count` and `sum` are still different.

[image: count]

If you want more explanation, you can refer to the following post, or [raise a support for help](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request).

*Related Post:*

[Azure App Service Metrics - How to interpret Sum vs. Count related to requests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48027668/azure-app-service-metrics-how-to-interpret-sum-vs-count-related-to-requests)